# Can't see my own questions on Team

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

I have recently created a team. It has 4 users.

I created 2 questions and answered one of them.
Other users can see my questions but when I access the team, I see no questions at all.

Is this by design or am I missing something in the team configuration?

Note:

I can see the questions on the main view, but I can't see them if I click on the team.

[image]   [image]

Comment: You're not getting a response, but given an issue this serious I'd bet a considerable amount that the devs are working on debugging this! Do they show up in the feed?

Comment: Hi! We had an issue with question lists in Teams last week that I believe was resolved. Is this problem still occurring for you?

Comment: @AdamLear: Hi Adam. Next time I post a question I will report back here.